# I have to find find letters among to string

Tags: c

I have to write a code to make double to real numbers but I have lots of trouble with that.

"#5p56.02#" with this input I must have "Invalid! scanned p character among input" or "###33##5" with this it must give me output "Invalid! There is a gap sequence between non-blanket characters."(# means gap tho)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char str[20];
   int i, frequency = 0;

   printf("Enter a string: ");
   gets(str);

   for(i=0;str[i]!='\n'; ++i)
   {
       if(' '== str[i])
           ++frequency;
   }

   printf("Frequency of %d", frequency);

   return 0;
}
```

I'm stuck with this and I dont know what would I do.

Comment: Your question doesn't match the the code. Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: Also what is "make double to real number" supposed to mean?

Comment: The loop won't terminate correctly with `str[i]!='\n';` but if you use the better `fgets()` it often will. But it's still not the way to test for end of string, which ends with `'\0'`.

Comment: `str[i]!='\n'` -> `str[i] != 0`, but my other 2 comments still stand.

Answer (score 0):

The %s will scan until a next space, you can't scan multiple words without a certain mask.

You could use the mask "[^\n]" this mask will scan everything until \n appears

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
   char string[50];
   int i, frequency = 0;

   printf("Enter a string: ");
   scanf("%[^\n]", string);

  for(i=0;i<strlen(string);i++)
   {
       printf("%c,", string[i]);
       if(string[i] == ' ') {
           frequency++; 

       }
   }

   printf("Frequency of %d", frequency);

   return 0;
}
```

The problem is, with this mask, you will have to figure out how to stop the loop, i tried on online compiler and had some issues using string[i] != '\n'

**Edit:** updated using strlen, and it's working fine for me

The

```
 printf("%c,", string[i]);
```

is for debug cause.

Check this out to know more about masks
http://personal.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Personal/R.Bowden/C/scanf.html

Answer (score 0):

To detect the *"Invalid! There is a gap sequence between non-blanket characters."* condition, I'd strip the gap characters from the start and end of the string; if a gap remains, it's between other characters:

```
    char *sp = str;
    while (*sp == '#') ++sp;                    // skip over the leading gaps
    char *ep = sp+strlen(sp);                   // string end position
    while (ep > sp && *--ep == '#') *ep = '\0'; // erase trailing gaps
    if (strchr(sp, '#'))
        puts("Invalid! There is a gap sequence between non-blanket characters."),
        exit(1);
```

To detect the *"Invalid! scanned p character among input"* condition, I'd just try the conversion to `double` and check whether there were unrecognized characters:

```
    double real = strtod(sp, &ep);              // try to convert double
    if (*ep || ep == sp)                        // conversion failed at ep
        printf("Invalid! scanned p character among input\n", *ep), exit(1);
    printf("%f\n", real);
```